# Individual properties of an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, this

Let's say I have 5 buttons. When a client presses one of them, JS sends `this` object to a function that changes button's state by accessing let's say `this.state` variable. The problem I am having is that I do not know how to make those individual variables in JS, so that every single button would have its individual variable that is not used by other buttons. I could make this work using CSS and changing some kind of CSS property, for example a CSS property that does not do anything to an element in a page, but can contain different properties, like numbers from 0 to 2, which would represent states. But this would not look so nice, because that is not what CSS is for :) I was wondering if anyone at this website know a way to create these individual variables? I am pretty new to JS and I know that I need to read about it, but now I am struggling with this problem and cannot locate a solution on search engines. Thanks to everyone who is going to help!

Comment: um, since `this` refers to the button that was pressed (at least, assuming you attach the event to the button it should), then each button will have its own `this.state` property, unique to itself.

Comment: so you are telling me that if I have 5 images that can be clicked and if a client clicks on them, then I can access `this.state` variable just by trying to get the value of it? is it created automatically if I try to set it?

Comment: Could you not create a variable for each button then use if statements to display whatever properties you desire, according to the button pressed?

Comment: Adam, I could, but I do not know how many "buttons" are going to be in the page, because the number will change in time. That's why I am using `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each button on your page is an instance of the object type "HTMLButtonElement". What this means is that you can treat it just like any other object.

Let's say that instead of a button, you just have `var me = {};`. You can very easily write
`me.state = true;` and it will create the propery on the object.

Now let's say you have two objects, `var btn1 = {}, btn2 = {};`. Set `btn1.state = true;`. Even though they are instances of the same object type (in this case, the generic "Object" type), `btn2.state` has not been affected.

In addition, accessing a property that doesn't exist returns the special value `undefined`. This value is considered to be `false` when used in a loose comparison (ie. just `if( btn2.state)` or
`btn2.state == false`). This means that it doesn't matter if you don't explicitly define it in advance, because it will behave just like a `false` value.

Another thing to consider is that, even though two variables may contain different instances of the same object type (such as the `btn1` and `btn2` above), they are not equal, because they are different instances. Consider the following:

```
var btn1 = {}, btn2 = {};
alert(btn1 == btn2); // false
var btn1copy = btn1;
alert(btn1 == btn1copy); // true, both variables point to the same instance
```

"btn1copy" isn't really an appropriate name in the above code. It's not a copy of the instance, it's a copy of the reference. This means that, because we've explicitly set `btn1` and `btn1copy` to be equal, changes to one *will* affect the other. Observe:

```
var btn1 = {}, btn2 = {}, btn1copy = btn1;
btn1copy.state = true;
alert(btn1.state); // true
alert(btn2.state); // undefined
```

I hope this helps you understand JavaScript objects a bit more. And if I've only confused you further, then I apologise! Please let me know if I can help with your understanding any more.

Comment: Thanks. Even though, you overcomplicated your answer, I found that if I set `this.state`, it does actually create itself. Problem solved!

Comment: Heh, yeah, I did get a bit carried away, didn't I? Ah well, glad I could help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

you can set any property on an element like so:

```
var currentEl = document.getElementById('myButton');
currentEl.state = 0;
currentEl.favouriteColour = "purple";
currentEl.thing = "hello"

var currentEl = document.getElementBytagName('input')[0];
currentEl.state = 0;
currentEl.favouriteColour = "purple";
currentEl.thing = "hello"
```

**EDIT:**

or you could create an object then add that to the element as a property:

```
var settings = {
    'id': 'myId',
    'colour': 'red',
    'thing': 'something
};
```

then:

```
var currentEl = document.getElementBytagName('input')[0];
currentEl.settings = settings;
```

then you could access them like:

```
alert(currentEl.settings.colour);
```

Comment: This would work, although use a wrong attribute name (like className, id, etc.) and you're in trouble. This method is not safe!

Comment: @Borre Most basic code editors colour-code keywords such as `id`, `className`, etc., so you would know immediately if you're at risk of using a reserved word.

Comment: @AdrianRoworth agreed, but nobody could mention all attributes in this list: for(var i in document.createElement('div')){console.log(i);}

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I still have to find the first code editor that highlights these attributes, since they are not reserved words in Javascript